# MYSQL_ROW and row[0] to string type?

Tags: mysql, c, api, c-strings

When using MYSQL C API to query results.  The results are returned as a `MYSQL_ROW` type, which according to the MYSQL C API documentation, I can easily `printf("%s", row[0])`.  But what if I want to transfer the contents of `row[0]` into a string or a char*?

Answer (score 1):

The %s format is only supposed to accept char* so from your description it looks like MYSQL_ROW is really a char** and taking row[0] will yield a char* anyway.

I don't see how using sprintf() (or the safer but non standard asprintf()) would be of any benefit but you may consider it if it makes you feel better.

Comment: Any form of manipulation seems to give me a run time error.
casting it as a string, strcpy, sprintf, etc etc

So has anybody found a way? It's hard to believe that an API would only allow users to retrieve results and print them out but not allow you to store it in memory.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [sprintf()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf), but you will still need to know the length of the string contained in row[0] so you can allocate enough memory.

Caveat: BCS correctly points out that your data will be truncated if row[0] contains extra nul bytes. If you know how much data is stored in row[0], using [memcpy()](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/memcpy/) is probably a better solution.

Comment: be warned however that if you do this, it will stop at the first \0

Answer (score 0):

> But what if I want to transfer the contents of row[0] into a string or a char*?

Use `mysql_fetch_lengths` to determine the length of the array in the `MYSQL_ROW`. Because there is 1 or more columns in the row, there can be 1 or more lengths.

According to [27.8.5 C API Data Structures](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/c-api-data-structures.html) documentation:

> `MYSQL_ROW`
>
> This is a type-safe representation of one row of data. It is currently
>   implemented as an array of counted byte strings. (You cannot treat
>   these as null-terminated strings if field values may contain binary
>   data, because such values may contain null bytes internally.) Rows are
>   obtained by calling `mysql_fetch_row()`.

Then, the [`mysql_fetch_row`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-fetch-row.html) documentation gives this example:

```
MYSQL_ROW row;
unsigned int num_fields;
unsigned int i;

num_fields = mysql_num_fields(result);
while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(result)))
{
   unsigned long *lengths;
   lengths = mysql_fetch_lengths(result);
   for(i = 0; i < num_fields; i++)
   {
       printf("[%.*s] ", (int) lengths[i],
              row[i] ? row[i] : "NULL");
   }
   printf("\n");
}
```

---

Here is an example of using it to count rows in a table. The table was populated from the FTC's [Do No Call violations](https://www.ftc.gov/site-information/open-government/data-sets/do-not-call-data).

```
MYSQL_RES* res = NULL;
MYSQL row;

const char SELECT_STMT[] = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM blacklist_ftc";
if (mysql_query(mysql, SELECT_STMT) != 0)
{
    /* handle error */
    goto finish;
}

if ((res = mysql_store_result(s_mysql)) == NULL)
{
    /* handle error */
    goto finish;
}

if (mysql_num_fields(res) != 1 || mysql_num_rows(res) != 1)
{
    /* handle error */
    goto finish;
}

char buf[32];
unsigned long* length;

row = mysql_fetch_row(res);
length = mysql_fetch_lengths(res);

if (row == NULL || length == NULL)
{
    /* handle error */
    goto finish;
}

size_t size = length[0] < sizeof(buf)-1 ? length[0] : sizeof(buf)-1;
memcpy(buf, row[0], size);
buf[size] = '\0';

unsigned long count = (unsigned long)atoi(buf);

finish:

if (res)
{
    mysql_free_result(res);
    res = NULL;
}
```